# Booting Linux with different security configurations

Tags: embedded, boot-loader

On an embedded system, we need to boot a Linux partition in several "flavors":

- an operational mode where sensitive services are disabled (e.g. sshd);
- an integration mode where such services are enabled.

The expected process is to detect specific GPIOs signals at startup.

The bootloader is U-Boot, and already reads those GPIOs.

I was thinking of letting U-Boot pass some specific argument to the Linux kernel, and then let startup scripts parse /proc/cmdline in order to alter their behaviour accordingly.

The other obvious solution would be to let the startup scripts reacquire the GPIOs once they are started, but this solution doesn't seem robust to signal jitters (some of them are dependant on an operator holding a button...)

- Are there any drawbacks to the "kernel argument" solution ?
- Did I miss any other simple solutions ?

Sincerely,

Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any drawbacks to the "kernel argument" solution ?

I don't think so.

> Did I miss any other simple solutions ?

I would go on the `kernel` solution and use a specific runlevel.
If i understood well your needs, the integration mode will implement the same things than production/operation mode but with stuff added (ssh, etc...).

So i would use runlevel 4 for operation mode and runlevel 5 for integration mode.

See manpage for [runlevel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/runlevel.8.html) and more globally for [boot](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/boot.7.html)

Comment: Thank you, i like the runlevel idea, it is pretty neat.

Comment: Then accept answer please ;-)